# if all roots of polynomial $ax^n+bx^{n-1}+cx^{n-2}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$ are real numbers, prove $b^2 - \frac{2n}{n-1}ac\ge0$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, induction

$n\ge2$ is a natural number. $a,b,c$ are real numbers $(a\not= 0)$. if all roots of polynomial $ax^n+bx^{n-1}+cx^{n-2}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$ are real numbers then prove
$$b^2 - \frac{2n}{n-1}ac\ge0$$

Comment: What’s your thoughts?

Comment: @farnood gholampoor Show your attempts and I'll show you my solution.

Comment: @farnood Look [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1540675p9320326), no offering necessary. Take into account that if $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are the roots, then their sum is $-b/a$ (the $a$ in the link), and the sum of their pairwise products is $c/a$ (the $c$ in the link). Take also into account that in the link there are a few $\prod$ that should be $\sum$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Vieta formulas we have $$x_1+...+x_n = -{b\over a}$$ and $$\sum_{i\ne j} x_ix_j = {c\over a}$$ Then by Cauchy inequality in second line $$b^2 =a^2(x_1+...+x_n)^2 = a^2(2{c\over a}+\sum x_i^2)$$
$$\geq 2ac +a^2{1\over n}(\sum x_i)^2=2ac +{b^2\over n}$$
and we are done. No need for calculus.

Answer (score 4):

By Rolle's theorem, if a polynomial has $n$ roots, then its derivative has at least $n-1$ roots (and of course, if that's the degree, that bound is exact).

By induction, the $(n-2)$th derivative of our polynomial has $2$ real roots.

Note that the $(n-2)$th derivative is $\frac{n!}{2}ax^2+(n-1)!bx+(n-2)!c$ and its discriminant is $(n-1)!^2b^2-2n!(n-2)!ac=(n-1)!^2(b^2-\frac{2n}{n-1}ac)$ and  that a quadratic polynomial has $2$ real roots (counting with multiplicity) iff its discriminant is non-negative.